# Why we need to provide Repository singleton as injected params are already singleton?

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

I am new on project I have this line of code in `AppModule`

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun articleRepository(apiSeResource: ApiResourceArticles, preferences:SharedPreferences): ArticlesRepository {
    return ArticlesRepository(apiResource, preferences)
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun apiResourceArticle(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiResourceArticles{
    return retrofit.create(ApiResourceArticles::class.java)
}
```

I am  wondering why we need to have `ArticlesRepository` in `AppModule`.
I see we are injecting the constructor, but why do we need to provide the instance of `ArticleRepository` as Singleton? What is the need for it?

Comment: Better question is, why do you have the provider method if you could just annotate `ArticlesRepository`'s constructor with `@Inject` and you wouldn't need this `@Provides` method anymore.